# Magento 2 - Why is it showing "Please specify at least one search term"?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.1.5

I'm doing many advanced searches on my Magento 2.1.5 and each consult is showing this message below:

[image]

My URLs are like:

**mystore.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?brand=859**

**mystore.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=Test&sku=&description=&short_description=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&manufacturer%5B%5D=263&credit_rate%5Bfrom%5D=&credit_rate%5Bto%5D=**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having this problem and I cannot figure out why, either I am making a mistake or it is a bug

The error is thrown (IMO) on line 228 in model:

```
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced

throw new LocalizedException(__('Please specify at least one search term.'));
```

The advanced search model is passed filters with the addFilters method, I am trying to search via a multiselect attribute and I am receiving the same error as you despite every parameter seeming to match up with the function.

```
$this->_catalogSearch->addFilters($value);
```

For value I have tried multiple ways with the same result as you, here are two I have tried:

```
$value = [ 'example_attribute_code' => 124 ];
$value = [ 'example_attribute_code' => [23, 124, 55] ];
```

To summarise, the error is thrown not when no products are found matching the search criteria - but when the model alleges no search criteria is provided.

Here is an issue registered for this on magento github - apparently disabling page cache can fix the problem (for testing, not production)
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8131